# Unable to extract the body of the email file in python

Tags: python

I am reading an email file stored in my machine,able to extract the headers of the email, but unable to extract the body.

```
    # The following part is working , opening a file and reading the header .

    import email
    from email.parser import HeaderParser
    with open(passedArgument1+filename,"r",encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
        msg=email.message_from_file(f)
        print('message',msg.as_string())
        parser = HeaderParser()
        h = parser.parsestr(msg.as_string())
        print (h.keys())  

       # The following snippet gives error
        msgBody=msg.get_body('text/plain')
```

Is there any proper way to extract only the body message.Stuck at this point.

For reference the email file can be downloaded from

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XlF206d5UrOW5xZ3FmV3M3Rzg/view

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get_body'

Comment: it seems like the method does not exist. Did you check the doc?

Comment: Was referring this document link  https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_body

Comment: This refers to `EmailMessage` not `Message`, you need do go one level down within the object. You are looking for `class email.message.EmailMessage`

Comment: Ok, how to achieve that?

Comment: I made an answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update**

If you are having the `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get_body'` error, you might want to read what follows.

I did some tests, and it seems the doc is indeed erroneous compared to the current library implementation (July 2017).

What you might be looking for is actually the function `get_payload()` it seems to do what you want to achieve:

> The conceptual model provided by an EmailMessage object is that of an
>   ordered dictionary of headers coupled with a payload that represents
>   the RFC 5322 body of the message, which might be a list of
>   sub-EmailMessage objects

`get_payload()` is not in current July 2017 [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_body), but the `help()` says the following:

> ```
> get_payload(i=None, decode=False) method of email.message.Message instance
>   Return a reference to the payload.
> ```
>
> The payload will either be a list object or a string.  If you mutate
>   the list object, you modify the message's payload in place.  Optional
>   `i` returns that index into the payload.
>
> Optional `decode` is a flag indicating whether the payload should be decoded or not, according to the Content-Transfer-Encoding
>   header (default is `False`).
>
> When `True` and the message is not a multipart, the payload will be decoded if this header's value is 'quoted-printable' or 'base64'.  If some other encoding is used, or the header is missing, or if the payload has bogus data (i.e. bogus base64 or uuencoded data), the payload is returned as-is.
>
> If the message is a multipart and the decode flag is `True`, then `None` is returned.

Comment: Gives me the following message msgBody=msg.EmailMessage.get_body('text/plain')
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'EmailMessage'

Comment: Thanks for  a detailed answer Fabien, sure most people will be benefitted by the answer.

Answer (score 32):

The 3.6 email lib uses an API that is compatible with Python 3.2 by default and that is what is causing you this problem.

Note the default policy in the declaration below from the docs:

`email.message_from_file(fp, _class=None, *, policy=policy.compat32)`

If you want to use the "new" API that you see in the 3.6 docs, you have to create the message with a different policy.

```
import email
from email import policy
...
msg=email.message_from_file(f, policy=policy.default)
```

will give you the new API that you see in the docs which will include the very useful: `get_body()`

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I just spent a good while wondering why the library and documentation don't match.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Still valid in Python 3.7.